# Get Url of remote server

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

A 3rd party server is calling my webhook api controller method.

Is it possible to get the URL of the server calling my magento server.

I tried looking for a solution but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check server access log.
if you know other server ip address or part of webhook url then you can wait for call:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep "1.2.3.4"
```

or just grep full log:

```
egrep "1.2.3.4|webhook" /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Comment: I need to check it in runtime, the URL of the other server hitting our server.